Brainstorming Python Selenium WebDriver UseCase with SSO
I have written and executed locally some Python Selenium test cases on my local Windows machine that utilizes SSO (ADFS) permissions to login to a webpage and grab a screenshot. (This works 100%)
I want to containerize those test cases for easier release capability (this process can be fluid, I'm still in the planning phase).
Systems involved
Windows -> utilizes SSO (THIS MUST BE THE WAY THIS IS DONE)
Linux Container Server (Localde on the same network).
What would be the best approach for a low-code or no code way of running those test cases through the Windows SSO session while keeping the code locally on the linux container? I have limited administrator rights on the Windows machine but full admin rights on the Linux container server.
I'm struggling to find a possibility that this could work, but also know that I do not want to in anyway pass SAML or other tokens/profiles back to my Linux container.
I have tried re-reading Selenium remote webdriver docs but I don't think this is the practical approach.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
